# USB 2.0 Signal Integrity Using HSETT

Tags: usb, test, controller

I am trying to test USB 2.0 Signal integrity (Eye Diagram). For doing that, USB IF Forum lets you download the EHCI HSETT Software from their website. However, I am not able to use it due to one persistent problem: No Host Controllers Found

Even though I have tried reinstalling the software, checking that I have the right 64-bit version and loaded the compliance driver manually(which keeps showing that it has errors in the device manager), I still get the same error. Can anyone help with getting this running?

Comment: Which host controller do you have? Modern XHCI won't work with an EHCI driver AFAIK.

Comment: I'm not sure. In Device Manager I get this:
**intel(R)6 Series/C200 Series chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1C26**

Comment: You are likely loading the latest software that works with xHCI hosts only. You need an older EHCI soft.